# Not getting projected fields with $group aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb

My aggregation query is:

```
db.POLICY.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"$_id",max:{$max:"$priority"}}},
    {$project:{name:1, AppList:1, status:1}},{$limit:1}
]);
```

It gives me a document with the _id field only.
Am I missing something?

Comment: It's because you didn't include those field in your previous stage (`$group`) result. Please can you show sample document.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `$group` does not contain any fields from the input unless you specify them. In other words, the output of `$group` will not contain `name`, `AppList` or `status`. It will however contain an `_id` and `max` field in this case. Read more on the `$group` field [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Comment: thanks for explanation. but how can i get max priority document using aggrigation.?

Comment: @sumitchoudhary Your query already finds the document with the max priority. I think what you want is to _not_ use aggregation, you want to use the regular find query [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/).

Comment: yes @David ,your are right but what about the performance when this query will going to execute 1000 times in a minute .?

Comment: @sumitchoudhary why don't you want to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33957775/edit) your question and add sample document and the expected result?

Comment: @sumitchoudhary You wont really know the performance until you try it out. Either way, you don't have much of an option. The aggregation framework doesn't have some magic bullet to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your comments from the existing answer above, looks like you want to get the document with the maximum priority value. One way you can go about this involves the use of the [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) operator which returns a value from the first document for each group. Order is only defined if the documents are in a defined order hence you'd need the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline step before implementing this in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** to order the input documents. The following example demonstrates this approach:

```
db.POLICY.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "priority": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "name": { "$first": "$name" }, 
            "AppList": { "$first": "$AppList" }, 
            "status": { "$first": "$status" }           
        }
    }
])
```

The above operation specifies an `_id` value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole and the [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) accumulator then computes the first `name`,  `AppList` and `status` fields for each document when ordered by the `priority` field descending, thus giving you the document with the maximum `priority`.